# How to convert string to an actual term in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have defined the following data type

```
data EventType = RUN_EVENT Integer | GIVE_ITEM Integer Integer ... deriving (Show)
```

and from some test, I'm retrieving data as below

> ["EVENT","6001","E","RUN_EVENT","6010"]

and when I process the data, if, for example, after "E", I get "RUN_EVENT", I would like to construct a data of type *EventType* having the value *RUN_EVENT 6010*.

To do that, I can create a huge list that basically says that if I face with "RUN_EVENT" then construct a value with value *RUN_EVENT*, but this would not be efficient, so is there any way to convert "RUN_EVENT" to a term *RUN_EVENT* so that I can use it as

```
exec = (stringToTerm "RUN_EVENT") 6010
```

Comment: What should happen if - like here - one constructor takes one `Integer` whereas the other takes *two* `Integer`s. That would mean the type of `stringToTerm` depends on the value (at runtime). Since Haskell is *statically typed*. The types should be known at *compile time*.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem _stringToTerm_ only takes the parameter as the name of the event, in particular "RUN_EVENT".  I will take of the parameters of the event separately. I mean I just want _stringToTerm_ to convert "EVENT_NAME" to an actualy term *EVENT_NAME* in the code.

Comment: yes, but what would be the *output* type? `Integer -> EventType`, well what if it is `"GIVE_ITEM"`? `Integer -> Integer -> EventType`, then what will you do with the second parameter in case of a `"RUN_EVENT"`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem To be clear, the type signature of __stringToTerm__ is :: String -> EventType

Comment: If it is anything, it is *not* `EventType`, since the construct needs *parameters* to construct a real `EventType`.

Comment: In my opinion, the only reasonable type would be `[String] -> EventType`, and thus let the function handle an entire "row" of parameters that need to be parsed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Those parameters are already set in the data, so I'm just going to pass them to as the parameters of *EVENT_NAME*. As  I said, the stringToTerm will just take String - event name - and give a term of type _EventType_.

Comment: `RUN_EVENT` does not have type `EventType`, it has type `Integer -> EventType`. Similarly, `GIVE_ITEM` has type `Integer -> Integer -> EventType`. These have different types so you can't return them from the same function.

Comment: @Lee Well... you are right. Any  suggestion then ?

Comment: @onurcanbektas: no those can not be set, since the `stringToTerm` should - depending on the *value*, return an `Integer -> EventType`, or an `Integer -> Integer -> EventType`.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want to write a parser e.g. `[String] -> Either ParseError EventType`.

Comment: @Lee Yeah, basically, but no idea how to go from "RUN_EVENT" to *RUN_EVENT* :)

Comment: @onurcanbektas: by writing a function like `f "RUN_EVENT" = RUN_EVENT; f "SOME_CONSTRUCTOR" = SOME_CONSTRUCTOR`. But those have to have the *same* type, or you have to pass some parameters, to handle the initialization (at least partially) such that the output type is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a debatably hacky solution using `Read`

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

data EventType = RUN_EVENT Integer | GIVE_ITEM Integer Integer ... 
     deriving (Read, Show)

parseChunk :: [String] -> Maybe EventType
parseChunk = readMaybe . unwords
```

This will work like

```
parseChunk ["RUN_EVENT","4"]     -->  Just (RUN_EVENT 4)
parseChunk ["GIVE_ITEM","1","2"] -->  Just (GIVE_ITEM 1 2)
parseChunk ["RUN_EVENT","4","5"] -->  Nothing  -- too many arguments
```

The reason it is hacky is that it relies on string manipulation to convert your data stream into a Haskell expression (which `read` parses).  If your parser grows in complexity, the approach may break down, or the hackiness of it might get out of hand. Imagine that one of your constructors takes a list, then you have to start inserting `"["` and `","` into the stream before you `read` it.

If you want more control, the better way is to write a proper parser, maybe using [Parsec](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.13.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html) or its ilk.  But you will either have to list all the cases manually or generate the cases using [generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-0.7/docs/Data-Generics.html).  My own aesthetic would allow the `read` solution to stand for now, but then switch to a formal parser if it looked like it was getting at all messy.

Comment: Nice solution actually

Answer (score 1):

Derive your data from Read type class. Then define the function as follows

```
    data EventType = RUN_EVENT Integer | GIVE_ITEM Integer Integer ... deriving (Show, Read) 

    stringToTerm :: String -> Integer -> EventType
    stringToTerm stringEvent n = read $ stringEvent ++ " " ++ show n
```

Keep in mind that the type annotation is important because of the read instance. The function stringToTerm can be partially applied to get what you want

Regards

Comment: How would you use it on a list of Terms with their arguments, as requested by OP?

Comment: If data is retrieve the same format always, the you can define stringToTerm by pattern matching the stringEvent variable. If not, I guess you should define your own parser with parsec library.

Comment: Then what's the point of the Read instance? You have arrived at the same function as I did.

Comment: The point is to partially apply the function stringToTerm so stringToTerm "RUN_EVENT" is itself a funciton for parsing the RUN_EVENT constructor . But yes, It is pretty close to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky solution, with `-XViewPatterns` for the added clarity

```
stringToTerm [] = []
stringToTerm ("EVENT":(read -> num):xs) = EVENT num : stringToTerm xs
stringToTerm ("RUN_EVENT":(read -> num1):(read -> num2):xs) = RUN_EVENT num1 num2 : stringToTerm xs
```

This allows you not to write a real parser, thus saving you the trouble, but will blow up if there's incorrect data

Answer (score 0):

A direct implementation of your question might be:

```
parseEventType :: [String] -> EventType
parseEventType ["EVENT", _, _, "RUN_EVENT", i] = RUN_EVENT (read i)
parseEventType ["EVENT", i, _, "GIVE_ITEM", j] = GIVE_ITEM (read i) (read j)
parseEventType x = error ("parseEventType: could not parse " ++ show x)
```

The GIVE_ITEM case might not be correct but it should give you an idea.

However, this has some issues, mainly around error handling: What do you do if arguments are not integers or if the shape of the list doesn't match up with one of your types? It would be easiest to use `Maybe`:

```
parseEventType :: [String] -> Maybe EventType
parseEventType ["EVENT", _, _, "RUN_EVENT", i] = RUN_EVENT <$> readMay i
parseEventType ["EVENT", i, _, "GIVE_ITEM", j] = GIVE_ITEM <$> readMay i <*> readMay j
parseEventType x = Nothing
```

This shows off the applicative style.